# How to show that an expression is 0 if FullSimplify never finishes

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a huge expression. And I have "checked" numerically that it is 0 for real value variables. However, due to the size and structure of the expression FullSimplify seems to be having a hard time.

**Question:** Are there any other tools than FullSimplify I can use or do you have any suggestions how to show hat a huge expression is actually 0?

Here is the expression if anybody wants to try out his suggestions:

I suspect (if it turns out that it is not true, I am still interested in the answer to the above question):

```
myFunc[EA,EC,J,t1,t2,xi,phi,sign1,sign2,1]-myFunc[EA,EC,J,t1,t2,xi,phi,sign1,sign2,-1]==0
```

Here is `myFunc`:

```
Clear[myFunc]
myFunc[EA_, EC_, J_, t1_, t2_, xi_, phi_, sign1_, sign2_, sign3_] := (EA + EC)/2 + (1/(2*Sqrt[6]))*sign1*Sqrt[2*(EA - EC)^2 + J^2 + 8*t1^2 + 8*t2^2 + xi^2 + (2*2^(1/3)*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]))))/((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])) + sign3*Sqrt[-4*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^3 + ((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^2])^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)*((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])) + sign3*Sqrt[-4*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^3 + ((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^2])^(1/3)] + (1/2)*sign2*Sqrt[(1/3)*(2*(EA - EC)^2 + J^2 + 8*t1^2 + 8*t2^2 + xi^2) - (2^(1/3)*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]))))/(3*((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])) + sign3*Sqrt[-4*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^3 + ((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^2])^(1/3)) - (1/(3*2^(1/3)))*((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])) + sign3*Sqrt[-4*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^3 + ((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^2])^(1/3) - (Sqrt[3/2]*sign1*((-EA + EC)*(J - xi)*(J + xi) + 4*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]))/Sqrt[2*(EA - EC)^2 + J^2 + 8*t1^2 + 8*t2^2 + xi^2 + (2*2^(1/3)*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]))))/((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])) + sign3*Sqrt[-4*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^3 + ((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^2])^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)*((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])) + sign3*Sqrt[-4*((1/16)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^2 + 3*(EA + EC)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (3/4)*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^3 + ((-(1/32))*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)^3 - (9/4)*(EA + EC)*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi]) + (27/4)*(-4*EA^2*EC + EC*(J^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2)) + EA*(-4*EC^2 + 4*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) + 2*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi])^2 - 18*(-4*(EA^2 + 4*EA*EC + EC^2) + J^2 + 8*(t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)*(-4*t1^2*t2^2 + 2*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + (1/16)*J^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + (1/4)*EA^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + EC*J*(-t1^2 + t2^2)*Cos[phi] - J*t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi]) + (27/4)*(EA + EC)^2*(64*t1^2*t2^2 - 32*EA*EC*(t1^2 + t2^2) + 4*EA^2*(4*EC^2 - xi^2) + J^2*(-4*EC^2 + xi^2) + 16*J*(EC*(t1 - t2)*(t1 + t2)*Cos[phi] + t1*t2*xi*Sin[phi])))^2])^(1/3)]];
(*extra line convenient for copy.*)
```

And it holds that:

All appearing parameters are real values. `sign1` and `sign2` are +-1.

**Edit 1:**

As requested, if you replace `J` with `J*sign4` in `myFunc` you get all solutions of this polynomial of degree 8 by changing `sign1`,`sign2` and `sign4` keeping `sign3=-sign4`:

```
p[x_]:=-4 (EA + EC) x^7 + x^8 - 2 x^6 (c^2 - 3 EA^2 - 8 EA EC - 3 EC^2 + s^2 + 2 (t1^2 + t2^2) +     xi^2) + 4 x^5 (-EA^3 - 6 EA^2 EC + c^2 (EA + 2 EC) +     EC (-EC^2 + 2 s^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) +     EA (-6 EC^2 + s^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 2 xi^2)) + (2 c EC (t1 -        t2) (t1 + t2) + 2 EA EC (t1^2 + t2^2) +     c^2 (EC - xi) (EC + xi) + 
EA^2 (-EC^2 + xi^2) + (EC s + 2 t1 t2 - s xi) (-2 t1 t2 +        s (EC + xi))) (2 c EC (-t1^2 + t2^2) + 2 EA EC (t1^2 + t2^2) +     c^2 (EC - xi) (EC + xi) +     EA^2 (-EC^2 + xi^2) + (EC s - 2 t1 t2 - s xi) (2 t1 t2 +        s (EC + xi))) + x^4 (c^4 + EA^4 + 16 EA^3 EC + EC^4 - 12 EC^2 s^2 + s^4 -     12 EC^2 t1^2 + 4 s^2 t1^2 + 4 t1^4 - 12 EC^2 t2^2 + 4 s^2 t2^2 +     16 t1^2 t2^2 + 4 t2^4 + 2 (-EC^2 + 2 (s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2)) xi^2 + 
xi^4 + 4 EA EC (4 EC^2 - 4 s^2 - 9 (t1^2 + t2^2) - 4 xi^2) +     2 EA^2 (18 EC^2 - s^2 - 6 (t1^2 + t2^2 + xi^2)) +     2 c^2 (-EA^2 - 8 EA EC - 6 EC^2 + s^2 +        2 (t1^2 + t2^2 + xi^2))) - 4 x^3 (c^4 EC + EA^4 EC +     EA^2 EC (6 EC^2 - 2 s^2 - 9 (t1^2 + t2^2) - 6 xi^2) +     EA^3 (6 EC^2 - t1^2 - t2^2 - 2 xi^2) +     EC (s^4 - EC^2 (2 s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2) +        2 (t1^4 + 4 t1^2 t2^2 + t2^4) + (t1^2 + t2^2) xi^2 +        s^2 (3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 2 xi^2)) +     c^2 (-2 EA^2 EC + EA (-6 EC^2 + t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 xi^2) + 
   EC (-2 EC^2 + 2 s^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 2 xi^2)) +     EA (EC^4 + 2 (t1^4 + 4 t1^2 t2^2 + t2^4) + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) xi^2 +        xi^4 + s^2 (t1^2 + t2^2 + 2 xi^2) - 
   EC^2 (6 s^2 + 9 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 2 xi^2))) + 2 x^2 (-EC^4 s^2 + 3 EC^2 s^4 + 6 EC^2 s^2 t1^2 + 2 EC^2 t1^4 +     6 EC^2 s^2 t2^2 + 8 EC^2 t1^2 t2^2 - 4 s^2 t1^2 t2^2 - 
8 t1^4 t2^2 + 2 EC^2 t2^4 -     8 t1^2 t2^4 + (2 EC^2 s^2 - (s^2 + 2 t1^2) (s^2 + 2 t2^2)) xi^2 -     s^2 xi^4 + 2 EA^3 EC (4 EC^2 - 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) - 4 xi^2) + 
c^4 (3 EC^2 - xi^2) + EA^4 (3 EC^2 - xi^2) +     EA^2 (3 EC^4 + 2 (t1^4 + 4 t1^2 t2^2 + t2^4) +        2 (s^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2)) xi^2 + 3 xi^4 -        6 EC^2 (s^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2)) +     2 EA EC (4 (t1^4 + 4 t1^2 t2^2 + t2^4) -        EC^2 (4 s^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2)) + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) xi^2 +        s^2 (3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 4 xi^2)) + 
c^2 (-EC^4 - 2 (t1^4 + t2^4) - 2 (s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2) xi^2 -        xi^4 + 2 EA^2 (-3 EC^2 + xi^2) +        2 EC^2 (3 (s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2) + xi^2) +        2 EA EC (-4 EC^2 + 3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 4 xi^2))) - 4 x (4 c s t1 t2 (-t1^2 + t2^2) xi +     c^4 EC (EC - xi) (EC + xi) + (EA^2 EC - EC (s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2) +        EA (EC^2 - t1^2 - t2^2 - xi^2)) (4 t1^2 t2^2 -        2 EA EC (t1^2 + t2^2) + EA^2 (EC - xi) (EC + xi) +        s^2 (-EC^2 + xi^2)) +     c^2 (2 EA^2 EC (-EC^2 + xi^2) +        EC (EC^2 (2 s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2) - 
      2 (t1^4 + t2^4) - (2 s^2 + t1^2 + t2^2) xi^2) -        EA (EC^4 + xi^2 (t1^2 + t2^2 + xi^2) -           EC^2 (3 (t1^2 + t2^2) + 2 xi^2))))
(*extra line*)
```

Comment: Have you tried `Simplify`? Or the option `TimeConstraint`? Sometimes it helps to do a little bit of simplification first using these methods.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried something like this `PossibleZeroQ[
 myFunc[EA, EC, J, t1, t2, xi, phi, sign1, sign2, 1] - myFunc[EA, EC, J, t1, t2, xi, phi, sign1, sign2, -1], Assumptions -> 
 sign1 ∈ {-1, 1} && sign2 ∈ {-1, 1} && 
 Thread[# ∈ Reals &@{EA, EC, J, t1, t2, xi, phi}]]` and it hasn't completed atfter a few minutes. I guess there is no hope with `Simplify` either. While testing numerically more extensively than in the answer below yielded always zero.

Comment: What's the origin of `myFunc`? It looks like it was generated by solving a polynomial of some sort. If that's the case, could you provide this information? We may be able to prove equivalence with that.

Comment: @ChipHurst The origin is indeed a Polynomial of degree 8 which Mathematica can split into two Polynomials of degree 4. The 8 Solutions turned out to differ only by four signs inserted into the right place. However, after I series-expanded the expression one sign dropped out no matter the order I tried. Thus I assumed that the expression is invariant under sign change which seems to be the case (numerical studies). I have added the characteristic polynomial to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try numerical tests. Usually I do something like this:

```
test = Flatten[{Thread[
    Rule[{EA, EC, J, t1, t2, xi, phi}, 
     N[Rationalize[RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {7}], 0], 50]]], 
   sign1 -> 1, sign2 -> 1}]
```

> {EA -> 5.5070945764813754067707123269662591210087398718144, 
>    EC -> 17.031759538199065766888472553401509641037985359085, 
>    J -> -30.131253476348398553051101194231010502960690964764, 
>    t1 -> 1.5102309452269758582666999059099783476519629716454, 
>    t2 -> -59.227461091403198733423282755362970908377276982560, 
>    xi -> -90.932057375163736635618092501815504589844494856171, 
>    phi -> 21.983047852241497252070159373899197116276883508615, 
>    sign1 -> 1, sign2 -> 1}

```
(myFunc[EA, EC, J, t1, t2, xi, phi, sign1, sign2, 1] - 
   myFunc[EA, EC, J, t1, t2, xi, phi, sign1, sign2, 1]) /. test
```

> 0.*10^-49

Running this many times as well as changing precision (here it is set to 50) one can see that the difference is always close to zero and gets closer when precision is increased.

Mathematica also has special function  PossibleZeroQ. But I would not hope much on that. As you probably know the problem of deciding if one expression is equal to other is undecidable in principle.